# There is input image field without any input image

Tags: javascript, html, mjs

I am building a WebApp and I am trying to add my `own` model instance in the place of default image field BUT I didn't find any **ImageField**.

**The Problem**

Page is showing `ImageField` but i didn't find any `image field in template`.

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.ImageField()
```

```js
  /* The main module for this is external. */
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js="filter"]');
if (elements.length) {
  import('https://elements.stoumann.dk/assets/js/css-filter.mjs')
    .then(module => {
    const jsClass = module.default;
    elements.forEach(element => {
      new jsClass(element, element.dataset, presets);
    });
  })
}

const presets = [
  {
  "name": "watercolor",
  "description": "",
  "value": "url('#squiggly-1') brightness(1.3) invert(0.17) saturate(2.6) sepia(0.25)",
  "values": [
    {
      "brightness": 1.3,
      "invert": 0.17,
      "saturate": 2.6,
      "sepia": 0.25,
      "url": "url('#squiggly-1')"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "faded-photo",
  "description": "",
  "value": "blur(0.2px) brightness(1.1) hue-rotate(5deg) opacity(0.9) saturate(1.3) sepia(0.4)",
  "values": [
    {
      "blur": 0.2,
      "brightness": 1.1,
      "hue-rotate": 5,
      "opacity": 0.9,
      "saturate": 1.3,
      "sepia": 0.40
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "old-horror",
  "description": "",
  "value": "url('#grain') grayscale(1) sepia(0.5) brightness(1.3) invert(0.8)",
  "values": [
    {
      "url": "url('#grain')",
      "grayscale": 1,
      "sepia": 0.5,
      "brightness": 1.3,
      "invert": 0.8
    }
  ]
},


];
```

```html
<div data-js="filter"

    >
    </div>
```

I think that the url in the template named `https://elements.stoumann.dk/assets/js/css-filter.mjs` is externel` js. BUT how can i make changes in externel  js ?

**What have i tried:-**

I tried to put many links but nothing worked for me.

When i try to replace the link then everything disappears in browser.

Any help would be Appreciated.

If someone knows why it is showing and how can i remove it then Please help, I will really appreciated your Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a default image field, you can pass the parameter of `previewImage` with your image path. Even if you have a external js, it allows you to pass you custom parameters and utilizes it during the constructor execution. Just add the attribute `data-preview-image` as below or refer [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Wahab896/buvgdo4j/21/):

```js
 /* The main module for this is external. */
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js="filter"]');
if (elements.length) {
  import('https://elements.stoumann.dk/assets/js/css-filter.mjs').then(module => {
        debugger;
    const jsClass = module.default;
    elements.forEach(element => {
      new jsClass(element, element.dataset, presets);
    });
  })
}

const presets = [
  {
  "name": "watercolor",
  "description": "",
  "value": "url('#squiggly-1') brightness(1.3) invert(0.17) saturate(2.6) sepia(0.25)",
  "values": [
    {
      "brightness": 1.3,
      "invert": 0.17,
      "saturate": 2.6,
      "sepia": 0.25,
      "url": "url('#squiggly-1')"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "faded-photo",
  "description": "",
  "value": "blur(0.2px) brightness(1.1) hue-rotate(5deg) opacity(0.9) saturate(1.3) sepia(0.4)",
  "values": [
    {
      "blur": 0.2,
      "brightness": 1.1,
      "hue-rotate": 5,
      "opacity": 0.9,
      "saturate": 1.3,
      "sepia": 0.40
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "old-horror",
  "description": "",
  "value": "url('#grain') grayscale(1) sepia(0.5) brightness(1.3) invert(0.8)",
  "values": [
    {
      "url": "url('#grain')",
      "grayscale": 1,
      "sepia": 0.5,
      "brightness": 1.3,
      "invert": 0.8
    }
  ]
},


];
```

```html
<div data-js="filter" data-preview-image="https://img.icons8.com/cute-clipart/2x/google-logo.png">
    </div>
```

**Note:**
A complete example with your external js is available on codepen, you can refer the link: https://codepen.io/stoumann/pen/MWeNmyb

Comment: BUT how can i add my `model instance` at the place of `ImageField` ? My instance name is **file**

Comment: Where have you defined this model? Is there any sample to which i can refer?

Comment: I want to use the filters and save it into `DataBase` and  i can only do that with access the models image instance in html.

Comment: Okay, so this you have done in python as well, am not well versed with that. I think you need to update your tags and provide python it it and it would be better if you update the description about how to bind your model with imageField or the input file type.

Comment: Well Thanks for your Time and Help. And also do you know any tutorial or github code that have `image filter and effects` ? Thanks Again.